# Why doesn't my program enters in my switch case "deleteRegistro" sending and getting with $_POST in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, post

My problem: I don't know why, my `switch` case is doesn't working properly and I don't know why if my AJAX `status == 'succcess'`.

My onClick function is in my button:

```
$data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $field)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>";
```

My function:

```
function Delete(id, tableName, field){
    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro con ID " + id + "?") == true) {
        $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", { 
            action: "deleteRegistro",
            id: id,
            tableName: tableName,
            field: field
        }, function (data, status){
                if (status === 'error') {
                    console.log("Not deleted");
                }
                else if (status === 'success') {
                    console.log("Deleted successfully");                                
                }
            });
    }
}
```

My switch case:

```
switch($_POST['action']){
    case 'deleteRegistro':
            
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
        $field = $_POST['field'];    
        echo "Hello!";
        ?>
            <script>alert("Hello!");</script>
        <?php 
        
        break;
}
```

As you can see, my AJAX `status == 'succcess'`:

[image]

This is my full code if you need to check it:

```
<?php

    use GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
    include_once(DIR_PLUGINS.'/alexcrudgenerator/main.php');

    $test = new GenerateCrud($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
    
    if ($_GET['action']){
        print_a($_GET['action']);
    }

    switch($_POST['action']){
        
        case 'datosTabla': // OK.
            
            //print_r($_POST['action']);
            $res = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
            echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            
            break;
        
        case 'deleteRegistro':
            
            $id = $_POST['id']; // Quiero obtener estas variables que he enviado desde la función Delete();
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName']; // Quiero obtener estas variables que he enviado desde la función Delete();
            $field = $_POST['field']; // Quiero obtener estas variables que he enviado desde la función Delete();
            
            echo "Hello!";
            ?>
                <script>alert("Hello!");</script>
            <?php 
            
            break;
            
        case 'showtable': // OK.

            $res = getEntireTable($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
            $tableName = json_encode($tableName);

            $field = json_decode($_POST['tableFields'],1)[0];
            //print_r($tableName);
            //print_r('<br>');
            //print_r($campo);
            
            foreach ($res as $data){                
                $data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $field)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>"; 
                $resultados['data'][] = $data;
            }           
            
            $resultados = json_encode($resultados); // 7 PROPIEDADES
            
            foreach(json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsDB){
                $fields[] = array('data'=>$columnsDB);
            }

            $fields[]['data'] = 'acción';
            $fields = json_encode($fields);
            
?>
            <head>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            
            <div class="container caja">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div>
                            <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed hover" style="width:100%" >
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            foreach (json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsTH){
                                                 echo '<th>' . strtoupper($columnsTH) . '</th>';
                                            }
                                            echo '<th>ACCIÓN</th>';
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>

                function Delete(id, tableName, field){
                    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro con ID " + id + "?") == true) {
                        $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", { 
                            action: "deleteRegistro",
                            id: id,
                            tableName: tableName,
                            field: field
                        }, function (data, status){
                                if (status === 'error') {
                                    console.log("Not deleted");
                                }
                                else if (status === 'success') {
                                    console.log("Deleted successfully");                                
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
                    
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var datos= <?=$resultados?>;
                    var dynamicColumns = <?=$fields?>;
                    datos = JSON.stringify(datos);
                    
                    $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
                        "language": {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "scrollX": true,

                        "ajax":{
                            "url": '<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/',
                            "method": 'POST',
                            "data":{action: "datosTabla", datos: datos}
                        },

                        "columns": dynamicColumns
                    });
                })
            </script>
<?php
        break;      
}
?>
```

Can someone give me a hand? I really don't understand.

If the `status == 'success'`, it means that the POST request has been sent successfully, so I should go into my `case switch` and print a "Hello!".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your printing out `$_GET['action']` but your switch is on `$_POST['action']`. Seems like a typo to me.

Comment: `I should go into my case switch and print a "Hello!".`...no, you told the code to write "Deleted successfully" in the console (via `console.log("Deleted successfully")`) when status is "success". You didn't tell it to do anything else. You can't embed `<script>alert("Hello!");</script>` in an AJAX response, that makes no sense - just let the javascript receiving the response decide what to display on the screen.

Comment: @KhorneHoly Yes, yes, I'm using `$_POST`, I just was testing some things. You can ignore `$_GET['action']`. Thank you anyway!

Comment: JS can use the content which came back from the server (which should include the echoed Hello (you need to get rid of the `<script` bit)) - it's available via the `data` parameter to your callback, which you've ignored so far.

Comment: @Caín then you should overhaul your question, add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and remove the other noise that is misleading like your $_GET test.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, ofc, for now, I'm not deleting anything, just creating a message in console.log, yes, I know. I'm just wondering why I can't enter in the case because, okay, maybe `alert` is wrong, but what about `echo`? Also, I tried with `print_r()` but but shows nothing. I guess is because I'm not entering in switch case `deleteRegistro`, right?

Comment: `I'm just wondering why I can't enter in the case`...what makes you think it hasn't entered the case? Like I said, you aren't inspecting the `data` value which came back from the server, so you've no idea what PHP actually echoed. Remember this is an AJAX request, the response goes back into a JS variable, not directly onto your page. (After all, if it _did_ go back directly onto the page, where would you expect it to show up? At the top? The bottom? Where? There's no logical place, because the page already exists. It's up to JS if/where/how to display the response. That's why AJAX is great.)

Comment: @KhorneHoly Okay, thank you. I will try to compress and reduce my code and I will edit my question!

Comment: @ADyson Yes, exactly. I will try to print my `data` in my JS before sending. Thank you!

Comment: `before sending`...huh?, I'm talking about `data` as in `function (data, status){`...this is the data which _comes back_ from the server, _after_ sending the AJAX request. I think you maybe need to go read up on the basics of what AJAX is and how it works, you don't seem to have fully understood the fundamental concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned in the question where the `switch` case is on, I assume its in `<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/"` index.php file ok?

So you are posting the data to a php file using Ajax and Ajax successfully posts the data, but how come you can expect that `hello` to be displayed on the screen?

As I have mentioned in my previous answer the output of the php file where switch case exist will not be displayed, `$.post` method just posts the data to the file it won't redirects to the file.

for your need I suggest you to use the hidden form to post the data to the file.

Modified delete function would be..

```
function Delete(id, tableName, field){
    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro con ID " + id + "?") == true) {
document.getElementById("postid").value = id;
document.getElementById("postTablename").value = tableName;
document.getElementById("postfield").value = field;
document.forms['deleteform'].submit();
         //Commenting old function
        /*$.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", { 
            action: "deleteRegistro",
            id: id,
            tableName: tableName,
            field: field
        }, function (data, status){
                if (status === 'error') {
                    console.log("Not deleted");
                }
                else if (status === 'success') {
                    console.log("Deleted successfully");                                
                }
            });*/
    }
}
```

Now add a form `deleteform` in html code
note:- add before you use this script for function `Delete()`

```
<form name="deleteform" action="<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="postid" name="id" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="postTablename" name="Tablename" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="postfield" name="field" value="">
</form>
```

After this form get submit you will be entering to your php file in the given URL, here you can do whatever you want play with the data you got from post method.

If you don't want to redirect to you php file containing switch case just display `data` you got from the page.

```
function Delete(id, tableName, field){
    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro con ID " + id + "?") == true) {
        $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", { 
            action: "deleteRegistro",
            id: id,
            tableName: tableName,
            field: field
        }, function (data, status){
                if (status === 'error') {
                    console.log("Not deleted");
                }
                else if (status === 'success') {
                    console.log("Deleted successfully" + "This is the response:- " + data);                                
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Now you can see what is the response of the file in console, in your case it should show you `hello` as you haven't echoed anything else.